# new controller is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-routing

I'm using **CodeIgniter**. I set my default controller is '`cart`'. And i add one more file in Controller folder that name is `admin.php`. admin.php having following code,

```
<?php

    class Admin extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index()
        {
            echo 'Hello World!';
        }

    }

?>
```

If i give the url like `http://lo...host/codeigniter/admin` means, It shows 404 Not Found. If i give `http://lo...host/codeigniter/`, It shows cart page as good.

And if i change default controller in routes.php as '**admin**', `http://lo...host/codeigniter/` shows 'Hello World!'

Answer (score 5):

Seem like your are not removing index.php from your URLs. Try to access to this URL:

```
http://lo...host/codeigniter/index.php/admin
```

If it works, then add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

More info:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Above URL is working. I replaced this code in .htaccess file (system/.htaccess, application/.htaccess, application/cache/.htaccess ). But no use. Can you?

Comment: Check that you have mod_rewrite enabled and AllowOverride All in your virtual host configuration. For example this is one of my virtual host  file: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot /home/rafa/www/mysite/web/

    <Directory /home/rafa/www/mysite/web/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: In your virtual host config file. In your local machine, perhaps it is in /etc/apache2/sites-available or /etc/httpd/sites-available

Comment: i didn't get this path in my localhost.

Comment: What system are you using? Linux (what distro?), Windows, Mac?

Comment: Windows 7, WAMP server 2.2

Comment: Then look at: c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apachexxxx\conf\httpd.conf or in the directory where you install wamp if it's other than c:\wamp